# Excel Drop Down Sorting

Tags: excel, sorting, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a data entry Excel sheet and have a drop down column with a unique ID.  In order to make data entry faster, I'd like the largest number (and most recent) to appear at the top of the list.

This is the formula for the drop down lookup

```
=OFFSET(Surveys!$S$1,1,0,COUNTA(Surveys!$B:$B)-1,1)
```

and currently returns this as an example

```
621378 on 05/09/2010 at 06:51 by JJ
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide more details on what you have currently (maybe a screenshot of what you have so far (relevant portions only))

Comment: it is possible with VBA using a Worksheet_Change Event. Are you trying to have the list sorted by the `id (621378)` portion each time a new one is added to column B (thinking this based on your dynamic formula for the list lookup?

Comment: That's exactly what we're trying to do, but we have VERY little experience with VBA.  Could you provide some code or guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without VBA. Look at this article on [making a sorted list using array formulae](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/27/sorting-text-cells-using-array-formula/). So make a sorted list in Survey!C:C and reference it in your offset.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Switching the < signs to > sorted it in the correct order and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Short of writing a VBA code (and I'm not sure how one would do that), I don't think this is possible with Microsoft Excel.